# 「さえ」と「くらい」についての質問

Tags: grammar, sentence, learning

> A: 日本へ行くなら、簡単な日本語**くらい**話せないと苦労するよ。
> B: 日本へ行くなら、簡単な日本語**さえ**話せないと苦労するよ。

A文とB文どちらの方が自然な表現ですか？また、不自然なほうにはどんな違和感があるのか聞きたいです。教えていただけませんでしょうか！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず単純に事実としてはBは不自然で、Aが自然です。実際問題としては「さえ・・・ないと」という表現はあまり使われないと考えていいように思います。

（この部分は英語ネイティブスピーカーから異論コメントがあれば削除します）英語で考えても

> A. If you don't know at least basic Japanese,... 
> B. If you don't know even basic Japanese,...

がそれぞれ元の日本語文に対応すると考えると、やはりBのほうが変に感じるので、基本的には同じことの気がしています。

---

もう少し意味的な説明としては、元の文は「日本である程度苦労しないための（知識の）程度」について述べている文であるため「程度」の表現である「くらい」のほうが自然である、ということかと思います。

Comment: 詳しく説明ありがとうございます！よく理解しました❣️